# Use Pointer of one class in other class in C++

Tags: c++, nullpointerexception

I am using a priority queue and have two functions: enque and deque in a priority queue class. After enque function, the head points at the start of the queue and I want to call deque function in another class named as `HMtree`.  When I call it, it shows that the head points to NULL and gives an error.

Here is the code:

```
class HMtree  : public priority_que{

    priority_que qu;

    HMnode* calldeque()
    {
        HMnode* temp;
        temp = qu.deque();
        return temp;

    }
}
```

```
class priority_que{
public:
    HMnode* head;
    HMnode* tail;
public:


HMnode* deque()
{
        HMnode* temp = head;
        HMnode* maxp = head;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (maxp->frequency > temp->frequency)
            {
                maxp = temp;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        cout << "deleting " << maxp->value << " with the " << maxp->frequency << endl;

        

        return maxp;




    }
```

Comment: Do you intended to both inherit from and have a member of `priority_que`? Please show a [mre]

Comment: This seems like a confusion between two different queues. Your HMtree class inherits from `priority_que` and it has a `priority_que` member `qu`. That's two different queues. So I think probably you are calling `enque` on the inherited queue, and then you call `deque` on `qu` which is still empty. I think you probably need to remove the inheritance, but I am guessing because I can't see the rest of your code.

Comment: I want to call deque function but when I call it using another object of same priority que class it NULL the head pointer

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @john then how I will access the deque function of priority_que class ?

Comment: @BlackKite It isn't the same priority queue, that's the point of my comment (and Alan's comment). Please read it again. But in any case for a proper answer you need to post a complete program, otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: @BlackKite That would be very easy to show you, if you posted some more code.

Answer (score 1):

For example you might change your `HMtree` class like this

```
class HMtree {

    priority_que qu;

    HMnode* calldeque()
    {
        HMnode* temp;
        temp = qu.deque();
        return temp;

    }

    something callenque(something)
    {
        maybe_return qu.enque(something);
    }

}
```

Of course `something` and `maybe_return` is not real code. But without seeing your actual code I cannot guess what you really need.

But hopefully you get the idea, add a method to your `HMtree` class which calls the `enque` method on the `qu` object. It's really the same thing that you have already done with your `calldeque` method.